# how to run the saved Queries in MS Access 2013 in windows form. C#

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

I have saved some queries in MS Access. Which result some output table in MS Access. 
how do i call them in Windows Form Application though C#. 
and how do i Display the QUERY result in windows form application though DATA GRID.

I tried but can not figure out how to do?
Please help.

Query name: "**GrossMonth**"

The out put is One column table. or 1 value.

Please help

Comment: [Interop Assemblies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264733.aspx) in conjunction with some SQL maybe..?

Comment: It totally bounced over the head. Can you give me a brief details ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all add references to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao`. Then use this code:

```
var accessApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application();
accessApp.OpenCurrentDatabase(@"Database1.accdb"); //Change accordingly.
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.Database cdb = accessApp.CurrentDb();

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.Recordset recordSet = 
cdb.OpenRecordset(
"SELECT * FROM QueryName", 
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.RecordsetTypeEnum.dbOpenSnapshot); //Change query name accordingly.
while (!recordSet.EOF)
{
    Console.WriteLine(recordSet.Fields["FieldName"].Value); //Again change if needed. Just an example.
    recordSet.MoveNext();
}
recordSet.Close();
accessApp.CloseCurrentDatabase();
accessApp.Quit();
```

Comment: SELECT SUM(User_Mktng_Dtl.Total_Grocery_amount) AS Gro
FROM User_Mktng_Dtl
WHERE (((User_Mktng_Dtl.custmer_name)="rr") AND ((DatePart("m",[Date]))=12));


I want to Implement in C# windows from application . 
I done upto customer_name="rr" but DatePart is very Difficult